# "%1 is not a valid win32 application" Rust Command run fail

Tags: windows, rust, command-line

I'm downloading an executable via `curl` and try to run it afterwards. However, the Command object responsible for running it crashes with the following message: `%1 is not a valid Win32 application. (os error 193)`

Here's a snippet for better context:

```
let link = "https://download.bell-sw.com/java/18.0.1.1+2/bellsoft-jre18.0.1.1+2-windows-amd64-full.msi";

Command::new("curl")
    .args(["-O", link])
    .output()
    .unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("{err}"));

let program = format!("./{}", link.split('/').last().unwrap());

Command::new(program)
    .output()
    .unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("{err}"));
```

Comment: First debugging task: are you able to run the downloaded executable outside of Rust?

Comment: @kmdreko yes, i can

Comment: And by link you mean? Symlink? Shortcut?

Comment: How are you running the downloaded executable (when it runs successfully)? From Explorer, or standard Windows ternimal, or MinGW shell, or...?

Comment: @Anders "https://download.bell-sw.com/java/18.0.1.1+2/bellsoft-jre18.0.1.1+2-windows-amd64-full.msi"

Comment: @Cerberus do you mean how do i check if exe is not corrupt? I can easily run it through explorer and pwsh.

Answer (score 1):

A .msi file is not an executable. To install it you need to run `msiexec.exe /i "c:\path\to\installer.msi" /qn`.

To open the file like Explorer you would have to call the `ShellExecute` WinApi...

Comment: msiexec.exe doesn't seem to do anything on my machine. `PS D:\Docs\rustidea> msiexec.exe /i ".\bellsoft-jre18.0.1.1+2-windows-amd64-full.msi" /qn`

Comment: /qn is silent, remove it to see the UI.

Comment: it says that the installation package could not be opened. suggests to verify it. is the issue on my end?

Comment: Oh, i think i might have fixed it... After removing the `./` in `format!` the msiexec finally managed to launch the installer...